# Sql Server Select rows from one table if no date collected in another table within date range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have two table one is client team and another is CHeader, When i enter a record in client team i am supposed to collect data in CHeader (with kind column data as 'Ini Test') within 7 days. If the 7 days are passed and the Cheader data is not collected for that client then i should be able to get those results in query output. Note : only Kind with 'Ini Test' is valid data for this case. following is the query .

```
            CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClientTeam](
        [ClientTeamID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [TeamID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [ClientID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Startdate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK15] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
        (
        [ClientTeamID] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =   OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON  [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]

        GO

        insert into [ClientTeam] ([TeamID],[ClientID],[Startdate]) values(123,1,   GETDATE())
        insert into [ClientTeam] ([TeamID],[ClientID],[Startdate]) values(12,23, DATEdiff(day,2,GETDATE()))
        insert into [ClientTeam] ([TeamID],[ClientID],[Startdate]) values(12,25, DATEdiff(day,3,GETDATE()))


        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CHeader](
        [CHID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [ClientID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [TeamID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [Kind] [varchar](80) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK22] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
        (
        [CHID] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON   [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]

        GO



        insert into [CHeader] ([ClientID],[TeamID],[CreateDate],[Kind])   values(1,123,DATEdiff(HOUR,4,GETDATE()),'Ini Test')
        insert into [CHeader] ([ClientID],[TeamID],[CreateDate],[Kind]) values(5,123,DATEdiff(HOUR,4,GETDATE()),'Gen Test')
        insert into [CHeader] ([ClientID],[TeamID],[CreateDate],[Kind]) values(6,126,DATEdiff(HOUR,4,GETDATE()),'XYZ')
        insert into [CHeader] ([ClientID],[TeamID],[CreateDate],[Kind]) values(23,126,DATEdiff(HOUR,5,GETDATE()),'XYZ')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, you want to take data from ClientTeam and only join it to CHeader based on the criteria mentioned.

I would say select from ClientTeam and Left Join onto CHeader. You can Join ON 
C.ClientID = CH.ClientID AND C.StartDate > DATEADD(DAY,-7,CH.CreateDate) AND CH.Kind = 'Ini Test'

Comment: Yes , but your answer is not checking if the start date from clientTeam +7 is > currentdatetime . I should be able to get the clients whoes data is not present in clinical header for kind 'Ini Test' within 7 days of cliends start date

Comment: Well you can do that yourself, your explanation was not very clear. think about using the DATEADD function on the CreateDate and comparing it to GETDATE()